# How to display correct time in persistent live USB

Tags: live-usb, time, persistence

It seems that while booting in `persistent live USB`, the wrong time (GMT / UTC instead of local) is displayed (at least that's what happens in Lubuntu 12.10).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer from [HERE](http://krisrowland.wordpress.com/2009/04/09/fixed-gnome-clock-shows-wrong-time-gmt-utc-instead-of-local-in-persistent-live-usb-ubuntu-810/)

> sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata

After executing this, ensure the correct timezone was selected, then set this command to be run automatically and non-interactively at startup by adding it to System -> Preferences -> Sessions -> Add -> Command:

> sudo dpkg-reconfigure -f noninteractive tzdata

Although in Lubuntu I was not able to add new staff to session, the settings made with first command seem persistent.